# Vega lite: How to match speific y-axis field with x axis labels?

Tags: javascript, charts, vega-lite, vega

My data is in the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "pre_120": 0,
    "pre_90": 0,
    "pre_60": 0,
    "post_60": 100,
    "post_90": 150,
    "post_120": 200,
    "type": "Mango"
  },
  {
    "pre_120": 0,
    "pre_90": 0,
    "pre_60": 0,
    "post_60": 90,
    "post_90": 140,
    "post_120": 190,
    "type": "Apple"
  }]
```

Here I want to plot 2 lines in the chart, for each type i.e. 'Apple' and 'Mango'.

The x axis is fixed : ["Pre 120", "Pre 90", "Pre 60", "0", "Post 60", "Post 90", "Post 120"]

For the Y axis, I wanted to plot the specifics fields with the x-axis labels.

Example, for 'Mango', the first point for the line starting should be using field value "pre_120" to be plotted on the chart wrt "Pre 120" label present on the x-axis, "pre_90" field value to be matched with "Pre 90" label on the x-axis and so on till one line is formed for one row.

I have attached the link to the editor where I have made the framework but cannot understand how to use the y axis values.

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/5dc4bc6633fa2496cd3c79af6fd65a3f/chart_issue2.json

Below is the expected chart

[image: Expected resultant chart]

Comment: You are plotting pre_120 on the y-axis and the values for both records are zero. What are you trying to plot? BTW, one record has "type" and the other has "ac".

Comment: @David Thanks for the changes. I have corrected the graph. I had changed the keys and values to dummy values, hence, the mismatch.

Comment: OK - I'm still not clear what your end goal should look like. At the moment, the chart is plotting what you're asking it to.

Comment: @David I have added an image of the expected results on the chart.

Comment: Try the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
{
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
      "width": 800,
      "height": 200,
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {
            "pre_120": 0,
            "pre_90": 0,
            "pre_60": 0,
            "post_60": 100,
            "post_90": 150,
            "post_120": 200,
            "type": "Mango"
          },
          {
            "pre_120": 0,
            "pre_90": 0,
            "pre_60": 0,
            "post_60": 90,
            "post_90": 140,
            "post_120": 190,
            "type": "Apple"
          }
        ]
      },
      "transform": [
        {"fold": ["pre_120", "pre_90", "pre_60", "post_60", "post_90", "post_120"]}
      ],
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": "line",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "key",
              "sort": [
                "pre_120",
                "pre_90",
                "pre_60",
                "0",
                "post_60",
                "post_90",
                "post_120"
              ]
            },
            "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
            "color": {"field": "type", "type": "nominal"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. No matter how much I try, I can never find the solution in vega-lite's documentation. Even their Github discussions arent helpful. You have answered my other Vega related questions before as well. How did you learn the application so well?

Comment: Yes, it can be a bit confusing at first. I worked through all the examples and then read most of the issues to get the hang of it. Keep at it and things will begin to click.